# Replacing a Fragment with another Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a `Fragment` called `MyFrag` and I create two instance of this `Fragment`, frag1 and frag2. In frag1 I register a click listener, and in the callback of this click listener I want to perform a `FragmentTransaction` and replace frag1 with frag2.

I managed to replace `Fragments` in an `Activity` but `Fragments` don't have the `getSupportFragmentManager()` method. This is the code I am using:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, new Flashcard_Fragment(false, 3));
transaction.commit();
```

Comment: `new Flashcard_Fragment(false,3)` it is not recommended to use a parametrized Constructor for a Fragment, because default constructor is what the system uses when it recreates a Fragment. Use `setArguments(Bundle)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can just call `getFragmentManager()` in your `Fragment`.

The `FragmentManager` you get from `getFragmentManager()` is used to replace/add `Fragments` to the `Activity`.
The `FragmentManager` you get from `getChildFragmentManager()` is used to replace/add `Fragments` inside of other `Fragments`.

So it seems that you just need to use `getFragmentManager()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `getFragmentManager()` in the `Fragment` instead of `getSupportFragmentManager()`. `getSupportFragmentManager()` is only used in the `FragmentActivity`. Try this:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, new Flashcard_Fragment(false,3));
transaction.commit();
```

Also be sure that `Flashcard_Fragment` has an empty constructor as well! The OS requires `Fragments` to have an empty public constructor.

Comment: i also used getFragmentManager() but nothing happens, the fragments that i want to be removed is in a ViewPager, and when user click on a fragment of ViewPager it is Replaced by new fragment, i can do this outside of fragment class (onclick for thar, and write the method in activity class ) but in fragmetn there is a BIG NO.

Comment: You cannot perform `FragmentTransactions` in a `ViewPager`. You just have to remove it from the `Adapter` of your `ViewPager` and then call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the `Adapter`.

Comment: Do you just want to go to the second `Fragment` in the `ViewPager`? What are trying to do? You should have mentioned this in your question.

Comment: i want switch between 2 fragments in viewpager, in fact in every page of it.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? You have to explain to me in detail what you want to do and also show me the code of the `Adapter` you use for the `ViewPager`. Then I can help you solve it.

Comment: i just want to replace a fragment that is in a ViewPager by a completely new fragment(there was not in ViewPager already) by clicking on the fragment.

Comment: You need to just modify your `Adapter`. Same thing as if you would modify what is being displayed in a `ListView`. Edit the code of the `Adapter` into your question.

Comment: Is your problem solved? Or are you still having trouble?

Comment: no, i have the problem, but i think this is because of ViewPager and its Adapter, as you said:"You cannot perform FragmentTransactions in a ViewPager", in fact i want to create a flash card app, if you know better way tell me,i appreciate you.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean when you say "flash card app" but the problem you are having can be fixed very easily. It's literally just a few lines of code. As I said before, show me the code of your `Adapter` and I can tell you how to fix it.